# Angular 8 migration from angular 4.4. TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'intlTelInputUtils' in undefined

Tags: angular, webpack-4, intl-tel-input

I am using `ng2-tel-input intl-tel-input` for taking number inputs in my application. After updating all the libraries and dependencies, getting an error in the console after `ng serve`

I have updated all the libraries and dependencies using

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/cli
```

Also i have updated **`intl-tel-input`** library, but still the issues persists.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "prep-ui",
  "version": "0.18.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^8.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.6",
    "@types/jsdom": "^12.2.4",
    "@types/knockout": "^3.4.54",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.136",
    "@types/parse5": "^5.0.1",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.21.0",
    "angular-highcharts": "^4.1.0",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-http-file-upload": "^1.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "childnode-remove": "^1.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.14",
    "highcharts-angular": "^0.1.0",
    "html-webpack-externals-plugin": "^3.8.0",
    "inputmask": "^4.0.8",
    "intl-tel-input": "^16.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-bar-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^0.4.48",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
    "ng-sidebar": "^6.0.2",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.7",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2",
    "ng2-tel-input": "^2.0.3",
    "ng2-webstorage": "^1.8.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^0.7.0",
    "ngx-select-ex": "^3.5.2-ng4",
    "nouislider": "^9.2.0",
    "print-js": "^1.0.47",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
    "showdown": "^1.7.5",
    "source-map": "^0.5.7",
    "survey-angular": "^1.0.75",
    "survey-knockout": "^1.0.75",
    "surveyjs-widgets": "^1.0.75",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-war-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "wnumb": "^1.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.1.1",
    "@ngui/scrollable": "^0.9.1",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/knockout": "^3.4.53",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-typescript": "^0.8.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "~4.35.3",
    "webpack-auto-inject-version": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3.7.2"
  }
}
```

Error on console:

```
vendor.js:209114 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to 
          search for 'intlTelInputUtils' in undefined
            at m (vendor.js:209114)
            at vendor.js:209579
            at Object../node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js 
            (vendor.js:209583)
            at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85)
            at Module../src/app/shared/directives/intl-tel-input.directive.ts 
            (main.js:11870)
            at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85)
            at Module../src/app/shared/shared.module.ts (main.js:12967)
            at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85)
            at Module../src/app/authentication/authentication.module.ts 
            (main.js:1078)
            at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:85)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue by including js into angular.json file

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.js",
          "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js"
        ]
```

Also Dont forget to remove from ..\src\app\shared\directives\intl-tel-input.directive.ts

```
import 'intl-tel-input/build/js/utils';
```

Worked fine with version "intl-tel-input": "^12.1.5",

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in your logic. The error says:

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'intlTelInputUtils' in undefined
```

So what the code probably does, is something like this:

```
"somethingToSearch" in yourVariable
```

and yourVariable is undefined. The in operator cannot do somthing on undefined.

Make sure to skip the undefined or that the variable is a correct object.